# differentiation operator and matrix before it

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose I have the equation $E\dot x(t)= Ax(t)$ where $A,E\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Now I can think solution of this equation as kernel of the operator

$$T=(A-E\frac{d}{dt})$$

(1) Solution is a differentiable map $x(t):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ So what should I assume as a domain and range vector space for the operator $T$?

(2) is $E\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}E$ in general? I think yes, taking $D=\frac{d}{dt}$

as $\begin{pmatrix}1&5\\2&3\end{pmatrix}D \begin{pmatrix}x^2\\x^3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&5\\2&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2x\\3x^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2x+15x^2\\4x+9x^2\end{pmatrix}$

$D\begin{pmatrix}1&5\\2&3\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x^2\\x^3\end{pmatrix}=D\begin{pmatrix}x^2+5x^3\\2x^2+3x^3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2x+15x^2\\4x+9x^2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, differentiation is linear, even with matrix factors. As for solution space ... $C^1$ would be the classic one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful here!

If you search for a general solution it can make a difference if you consider $E\frac{d}{dt}x$ or $\frac{d}{dt}Ex$.

E.g.  $\dot x_1 +\dot x_2$ would require both $x_1$ and $x_2$ to be differentiable whereas $\frac{d}{dt}(x_1 + x_2)$ would not.

As a concrete example, consider $E = A = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$,

then $E\dot x = Ax $ has the general solution $x(t) = c_1 e^t \begin{pmatrix}1\\0 \end{pmatrix} + c_2 e^t \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix} $,

But $\frac{d}{dt}Ex = Ax$ would also admit solutions like $x(t) = \begin{pmatrix}+\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)} \\-\mathbb 1_{[0,\infty)} \end{pmatrix}$